# Getting a 404 on a route alias

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm new to Node and angular and trying to figure out why my app is throwing a 404. 
Here is the main error that I see in Firebug:

```
 Cannot GET /api/user
```

In my server.js I make a call to the routes:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 require('./routes')(app)
```

Within the routes folder I have index.js (which looks like it is called with the above require).

```
 module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(restUtils.buildUrl('/api/user'), require('./user-api'));
 }
```

restUtils just returns: '/api/user' and user-api is just another route within that same routes folder.
I can place a console.log right within the module.exports so I can see its making it there on server startup. It appears like it is generating the alias to api/user. However, when the app goes to find api/user it returns the 404.

Here is a snippet from user-api.js:

```
 var router = require('express').Router(),
     config = require('../conf/config'),
     logger = require('../lib/logger'),
     restUtils = require('../lib/rest-utils');
 console.log("Inside User-Api");
 router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    console.log("Inside user-api - router.get");
    if (config.debug && config.secured) logger.info('USER: ', req.user)
    var user = {
        id: req.user ? req.user.id : '',
        displayName: req.user ? req.user.displayname : 'Unknown User',
        roles: req.user ? req.user.appRoles : [],
        groups: req.user ? req.user.appGroups : [],
        profile: req.user ? req.user.profile : {}
    };

    res.format({
       json: function() {
          res.send(user);
       }
    });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

I see the first console.log on server startup but it never falls into router.get.

Please let me know if you think I should show more code at different spots - just not sure what is needed to try and figure out this 404! Maybe the user-api route is failing to load when it should be calling the router.get? I think I just don't know enough about routing and modules just yet.
Thanks!!

Comment: can you post all of user-api

Comment: ok... posted the rest of user-api.js. I'm guessing the req statements are pulling from the users cert. that is passed in when the user first hits the site. again, it never seems to make it into that router.get. thanks for looking!

Comment: can you try module.exports = router at the end of your user-api.js

Comment: tried that... same error. updated code above. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: huh, I thought nodejs should crash if you don't module.export on user-api.js.  what happens when you remove the restUtils.buildUrl and just use '/api/user' in index.js ?

Comment: Wow... that did it! It looks like the restUtils just returned that string - but I guess there was some difference. I up voted you comment but if you add that as an answer I will accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exist at

```
restUtils.buildUrl('/api/user')
```

which is returning a string 'api/user', it needs to be '/api/user'

Comment: I looked more closely... turns out the restUtils returned "api/user" not "/api/user"!

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
Cannot GET /api/user
```

So it tries to get a route which doesn't exists. You could ***add a get route*** for */api/user*, that would fix the error I guess.

```
app.get("/api/user",function(req,res){})
```

I hope thats may help you

Comment: I think you might be on to something here. I made those changes and while I no longer get the 404... firebug just shows the "GET user" with the little spinning wheel (like its still trying to load something). Eventually the status is: Aborted.